# Bootstrap Library reference breaks anchor hover function

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm feeling quite frustrated after finding out that the bootstrap button class seems to break the hover function in standard CSS.

I didn't really want to use tooltips, so I decided to try making my own grey box appear next to my button to display why it's disabled on hover. Here's my code:

**HTML**

```
 <a class="btn btn-danger disabled" disabled="disabled" href="" id="statement-delete" onclick="return false;">Delete
     <span id="delete-info"></span>
</a>
```

**CSS**

```
#statement-delete:hover #delete-info {
    display: block;
}

#delete-info {
    display: none;
    background: #C8C8C8;
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
}
```

I thought I surely must be doing something wrong until I used a JSFiddle, and it magically worked (before adding the Bootstrap reference). However, as soon as I added the reference to the Bootstrap, no hover...

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ga82Lbm5/1/

If you remove the reference to bootstrap at the left, you'll see that it works.

Is it possible to use the Hover function over a Bootstrap button? Or will I have to resort to using some custom jQuery to do this?

Comment: It doesn't work because you have disabled button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap adds the rule `pointer-events:none` to your code for disabled elements to prevent the hover from working. You can undo this by reverting the change with:

```
a.btn.disabled {
    pointer-events: auto;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ga82Lbm5/2/)**

Comment: Legendary, that's actually exactly what I want. In about 5 minutes, I'll accept your answer as the best. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you remove the property `disabled="disabled"` since you **want** the `hover` function. Logically, if you think about it, the element must be "enabled" for the `hover` to work. Similarly, you could also remove the CSS class `disabled` class for the same reason.

The thing is Bootstrap adds the property `pointer-events: none;` to the class `disabled`. The definition of this property  (*borrowed from Mozilla Developer Network* (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)) is :

> The CSS property pointer-events allows authors to control under what
>   circumstances (if any) a particular graphic element can become the
>   target of mouse events.

**You solution really is to nullify the effects of this property**.Thus, removing the aforementioned properties, this works. See below :

```css
#statement-delete:hover #delete-info {
    display: block;
}

#delete-info {
    display: none;
    background: #C8C8C8;
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    top: 48px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <a class="btn btn-danger" href="" id="statement-delete" onclick="return false;">Delete<span id="delete-info"></span></a>
```

Comment: I can see why events wouldn't want to be triggered on hover, but the button is conditionally disabled, and I want some feedback to the user as to why to hover for the user if they try and use the button.

Comment: @Reisclef Depends on your use-case & scenario, but ideally if a button is "disabled" per se, as a developer, my intention would be to keep it away from any sort of user interactions. In case, I want the interaction, I would enable the button.

Comment: Fair enough, I probably could have been more specific in my question as to exactly what I was trying to accomplish. That information is helpful, so I'll upvote it as well.